# All orders are not showing

Tags: python, django

I want to show all orders in a table of my panel but its not showing.Its showing in django admin but not showing in my panel.

Here is my Views.py:

```
class AdminPanel(View):
    def get(self, request):
        products = Product.get_all_products()
        cats = Category.get_categories()
        orders = Order.get_all_orders()
        args = {'products':products, 'cats':cats, 'orders':orders}
        return render(self.request, 'adminpanel/main.html', args)
```

Here is my HTML file:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Sno.</th>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Invoice ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Customer Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Phone Number</th>
      <th scope="col">Product Quantity</th>
      <th scope="col">Status</th>
      <th scope="col">Total</th>
      
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for order in orders %}
    {% if orders %}
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{forloop.counter}}</th>
      <td>{{order.date}}</td>
      <td>GNG#{{order.id}}</td>
      <td>{{order.fname}}</td>
      <td>{{order.phone}}</td>
      <td>{{order.quantity}}</td>
      <td>{{order.status}}</td>
      <td>{{order.price}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% else %}
    <h5 class="badge badge-danger">No Orders Found</h5>
    {%endif%}
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

in my model.py I have this method:

```
@staticmethod
    def get_all_orders(self):
        return Order.objects.all()
```

Model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product")
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField(datetime.datetime.today, null=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)


    @staticmethod
    def get_all_orders(self):
        return Order.objects.all()
```

Comment: What does `orders = Order.get_all_products()` do?

Comment: sorry it should be get_all_orders i corrected that but still same no data @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: but that function does not exists by DJango, you implemented that yourself normally. Can you share the details of this function?

Comment: Did you write custom methods on your models to get all objects? If so, please share the code since these don't look like standard django queryset code. Also with regards to fetching your orders, you used `get_all_products`

Comment: i did under the order model i have this method @staticmethod
 def get_all_orders(self):
  return Order.objects.all()

Comment: I added the model including the method I used

Comment: Ok it got solved i didnt define the variable in right function Thanks @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i didnt put orders variable in the right function

So the function will look like this ::

```
def admin(request):
orders = Order.objects.all()
params = {'orders':orders}
return render(request, 'adminpanel/mani.html', params)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `get_all_orders` is useless. It does nothing special. Just use in the View:

```
orders = Order.objects.all()
```